# non blocking tcp connect with epoll

Tags: linux, tcp, epoll

My linux application is performing non-blocking TCP connect syscall and then use `epoll_wait` to detect three way handshake completion.
Sometimes `epoll_wait` returns with both `POLLOUT` & `POLLERR` events set for the same socket descriptor.

I would like to understand what's going on at TCP level. I'm not able to reproduce it on demand. My guess is that between two calls to `epoll_wait` inside my event loop we had a SYN+ACK/ACK/FIN sequence but again I'm not able to reproduce it.

Answer (score 6):

It is likely for this to happen if the connect has failed - for example with "connection timed out" (for sockets doing a non-blocking connect, `POLLOUT` becomes set when the connect operation has finished for both successful and unsuccessful outcomes).

When `POLLOUT` becomes set for the socket, use `getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, ...)` to check if the connect succeeded or not (the `SO_ERROR` socket option is 0 in this case, and otherwise indicates why the connect failed).

Answer (score 4):

Here is some good information on [non-blocking tcp connect()](http://cr.yp.to/docs/connect.html).

When a socket error is detected (i.e. connection closed/refused/timedout), epoll will return the registered interest events POLLIN/POLLOUT with POLLERR.  So epoll_wait() will return POLLOUT|POLLERR if you registered POLLOUT, or POLLIN|POLLOUT|POLLERR if POLLIN|POLLOUT was registered.

Just because epoll returns POLLIN doesn't mean there will be data available to read, since recv() may just return the error from the non-blocking connect() call.  I think epoll returns all the registered events with POLLERR to make sure the program calls send()/recv()/etc.. and gets the socket error.  Some programs never check for POLLERR/POLLHUP and only catch socket errors on the next send()/recv() call.